# Mostrar en TextViews desde un llamado POST y RETROFIT2 en Android

Tags: java, android, rest, post

estoy tratando de mostrar lo que aparece en mi Postman, dónde esta dividido por diferentes gson y objetos:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Esta primera parte lo puedo mostrar sin problemas, pero a continuación abro

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

dónde hay mas información que necesito mostrar en mi app en diferentes textViews...

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y No solo eso, también tengo que mostrar lo que hay adentro de "rowset"

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

ya fui a la página "https://www.jsonschema2pojo.org/" donde me hizo un buen parseo,

Acá en el siguiente código es donde puedo loguearme con la autorizacion que me pide y tambien de paso recupero la primera instancia del gson

```
public class LoginUser {
@SerializedName("username")
@Expose
private String username;
@SerializedName("password")
@Expose
private String password;

@SerializedName("deposito")
@Expose
private String deposito;



public LoginUser(String username, String password, String deposito) {
    this.username = username;
    this.password = password;
    this.deposito = deposito;
}

public String getUsername() {
    return username;
}

public void setUsername(String username) {
    this.username = username;
}

public String getPassword() {
    return password;
}

public void setPassword(String password) {
    this.password = password;
}


@SerializedName("jde__status")
@Expose
private String jdeStatus;
@SerializedName("jde__startTimestamp")
@Expose
private String jdeStartTimestamp;
@SerializedName("jde__endTimestamp")
@Expose
private String jdeEndTimestamp;
@SerializedName("jde__serverExecutionSeconds")
@Expose
private Double jdeServerExecutionSeconds;

public String getJdeStatus() {
    return jdeStatus;
}

public void setJdeStatus(String jdeStatus) {
    this.jdeStatus = jdeStatus;
}

public String getJdeStartTimestamp() {
    return jdeStartTimestamp;
}

public void setJdeStartTimestamp(String jdeStartTimestamp) {
    this.jdeStartTimestamp = jdeStartTimestamp;
}

public String getJdeEndTimestamp() {
    return jdeEndTimestamp;
}

public void setJdeEndTimestamp(String jdeEndTimestamp) {
    this.jdeEndTimestamp = jdeEndTimestamp;
}

public Double getJdeServerExecutionSeconds() {
    return jdeServerExecutionSeconds;
}

public void setJdeServerExecutionSeconds(Double jdeServerExecutionSeconds) {
    this.jdeServerExecutionSeconds = jdeServerExecutionSeconds;
}
```

}

en esta parte no tengo ningun problema.

uso de interface el código siguiente:

```
public interface Conexion {

@POST("jderest/v3/orchestrator/MQ0302A_ORCH")
Call<LoginUser> getUser(@Body LoginUser users );
```

despues de recuperar esto ya se me complica, porque no estoy seguro de cómo seguirlo.

pongo todo lo que tengo en mi respuesta de gson

```
{
"MQ0302A_DATAREQ": {
    "tableId": "VMQ03421",
    "rowset": [
        {
            "CANTIDAD": 26,
            "NRO_CLIENTE": 24085,
            "ORDEN": 622682,
            "TIPO": "SO",
            "CLIENTE": "ROSA, JUAN RICARDO",
            "DEPOSITO": "          01",
            "FECHA": "17/11/2021"
        },
        {
            "CANTIDAD": 34,
            "NRO_CLIENTE": 24085,
            "ORDEN": 622634,
            "TIPO": "SO",
            "CLIENTE": "ROSA, JUAN RICARDO",
            "DEPOSITO": "          01",
            "FECHA": "29/10/2021"
        },
        {
            "CANTIDAD": 1,
            "NRO_CLIENTE": 11313,
            "ORDEN": 622626,
            "TIPO": "SM",
            "CLIENTE": "COSUFI S.A.",
            "DEPOSITO": "          01",
            "FECHA": "28/10/2021"
        },
        {
            "CANTIDAD": 1,
            "NRO_CLIENTE": 11313,
            "ORDEN": 622625,
            "TIPO": "SM",
            "CLIENTE": "COSUFI S.A.",
            "DEPOSITO": "          01",
            "FECHA": "28/10/2021"
        },
        {
            "CANTIDAD": 1,
            "NRO_CLIENTE": 11313,
            "ORDEN": 622628,
            "TIPO": "SM",
            "CLIENTE": "COSUFI S.A.",
            "DEPOSITO": "          01",
            "FECHA": "28/10/2021"
        },
        {
            "CANTIDAD": 1,
            "NRO_CLIENTE": 11313,
            "ORDEN": 622623,
            "TIPO": "SM",
            "CLIENTE": "COSUFI S.A.",
            "DEPOSITO": "          01",
            "FECHA": "28/10/2021"
        },
        {
            "CANTIDAD": 1,
            "NRO_CLIENTE": 11313,
            "ORDEN": 622624,
            "TIPO": "SM",
            "CLIENTE": "COSUFI S.A.",
            "DEPOSITO": "          01",
            "FECHA": "28/10/2021"
        },
        {
            "CANTIDAD": 1,
            "NRO_CLIENTE": 24085,
            "ORDEN": 622718,
            "TIPO": "SO",
            "CLIENTE": "ROSA, JUAN RICARDO",
            "DEPOSITO": "          01",
            "FECHA": "29/11/2021"
        },
        {
            "CANTIDAD": 1,
            "NRO_CLIENTE": 24085,
            "ORDEN": 622630,
            "TIPO": "SO",
            "CLIENTE": "ROSA, JUAN RICARDO",
            "DEPOSITO": "          01",
            "FECHA": "28/10/2021"
        },
        {
            "CANTIDAD": 1,
            "NRO_CLIENTE": 24085,
            "ORDEN": 622683,
            "TIPO": "SO",
            "CLIENTE": "ROSA, JUAN RICARDO",
            "DEPOSITO": "          01",
            "FECHA": "19/11/2021"
        },
        {
            "CANTIDAD": 1,
            "NRO_CLIENTE": 11313,
            "ORDEN": 622629,
            "TIPO": "SM",
            "CLIENTE": "COSUFI S.A.",
            "DEPOSITO": "          01",
            "FECHA": "28/10/2021"
        },
        {
            "CANTIDAD": 1,
            "NRO_CLIENTE": 11313,
            "ORDEN": 622627,
            "TIPO": "SM",
            "CLIENTE": "COSUFI S.A.",
            "DEPOSITO": "          01",
            "FECHA": "28/10/2021"
        },
        {
            "CANTIDAD": 2,
            "NRO_CLIENTE": 15187,
            "ORDEN": 622578,
            "TIPO": "SO",
            "CLIENTE": "T.A.E.S.A. AGRIC. GANADERA",
            "DEPOSITO": "          01",
            "FECHA": "18/10/2021"
        }
    ],
    "records": 13,
    "moreRecords": false
},
"jde__status": "SUCCESS",
"jde__startTimestamp": "2022-02-04T09:46:24.037-0300",
"jde__endTimestamp": "2022-02-04T09:46:25.483-0300",
"jde__serverExecutionSeconds": 1.446
```

}

acá mi clase dónde hace todos los llamados

```
 //conexión
    Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl(" http://137.116.116.34:91/")
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
            .build();

    Conexion conexion = retrofit.create(Conexion.class);

    String userName = "xx";
    String password ="xxx";


    //validación de usuario

    LoginUser logerse = new LoginUser(userName, password, "01");


   Call<LoginUser> call = conexion.getUser(logerse);
    call.enqueue(new Callback<LoginUser>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<LoginUser> call, Response<LoginUser> response) {
            if (response.isSuccessful()) {
                //sucursal.setText("code: " + response.code() + " Conexión exitosa " + "\n");

                LoginUser datareq = response.body();

                String content = "";
                content += "" + datareq.getTableId() + "\n\n";
                NRO_DE_PEDIDO.setText(content);


                String content3 = "";
                content3 += "" + datareq.getJdeStatus() + "\n\n";
                sucursal.setText(content3);


                String content4 = "";
                content4 += "" + datareq.getJdeStartTimestamp()+ "\n\n";
                NRO_DE_PEDIDO.setText(content4);

                String content2 = "";
                content2 += "" +
                        "" + datareq.getJdeEndTimestamp()+ "\n";
                NRO_DE_PEDIDO.setText(content2);



                Call <Rowset> call1= conexion.getRowset(logerse);
                call1.enqueue(new Callback<com.example.villamoreno.Rowset>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(Call<Rowset> call, Response<Rowset> response) {
                        if(!response.isSuccessful()){
                            Rowset datareq = response.body();

                            String content = "";
                            content += "" + datareq.getTableId() + "\n\n";
                            TIPO.setText(content);



                            String content2 = "";
                            content2 += "" + datareq.getRecords() + "\n\n";
                            TIPO.setText(content2);




                            List <Info> rowset= (List<Info>) datareq.getInfo();
                            for(Info d : rowset ){
                                { Info reqRowset = d;

                                    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                                        @Override
                                        public void run() {
                                            NRO_DE_PEDIDO.setText(reqRowset.getOrden()+ "\n") ;
                                            TIPO.setText( reqRowset.getTipo() + "\n");
                                            FECHA.setText( reqRowset.getFecha() + "\n");
                                            NRO_CLIENTE.setText( reqRowset.getNroCliente() + "\n");
                                            CLIENTE.setText( reqRowset.getCliente() + "\n");



                                        }
                                    });

                                }
                            }
                       }
                    }



                    @Override
                    public void onFailure(Call<com.example.villamoreno.Rowset> call, Throwable t) {
                        Toast.makeText(SegundoActivity.this, "conexion fallida", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        tabla.setText(t.getMessage());



                    }
                });


            }



                else{
                    Toast.makeText(SegundoActivity.this, "Login failed", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<LoginUser> call, Throwable t) {
            sucursal.setText(t.getMessage());

        }
    });
```

desde ya muchas gracias! alguna guía de como seguirlo seria muy útil!

Comment: Primeramente response.body() tiene un valores?

Comment: tengo entendido que es lo que se muetra en el postman, o me equivoco?

Comment: Si, pero debes asegurar se obtenga en la aplicación.

Comment: si, en la primera respuesta del response body me trae la informacion en la aplicacion, pero cuando ir por la segunda tanda, que seria 
 "tableId": "VMQ03421",
 "rowset" [ ...]
 "records": 13,
 "moreRecords": false

no puedo traerlo, que tambien imagino que es parte del reponse body